# how to add libraries to a make file

Tags: c, makefile

I'm editing an example file already in a library.  Inside the directory of the example, there is a Makefile that I have been using to compile and run the example.  I now want to add an additional library to this make file, I have tried copy and pasting the header and .c file into the library folder specified in the Makefile, but it is not finding it. Here is the Makefile code:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I../../include
CFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS = -L../../lib -L../../lib64
LIBS = -lbsapi

Biometry: main.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.c -o Biometry $(LIBS)
```

The library that I wanted to add came with a .h file and a .c file.  I have added those to the ../../include directory and made sure to add this to my code right below the previous #include

```
#include <tpl.h>
```

I am not sure what I am missing? The program ran properly before the addition of this library.

Answer (score 2):

Libraries are usually first built and installed to your system, so you can later add them to what seems to be `LIBS` in your Makefile (let's say your library's called "foo", `-lfoo`).

So you've got two options:

1. The "this actually deserves the name library" path: Find or write a Makefile to turn foo.c into a libfoo.so, install that, and then use `LIBS= -lbsapi -lfoo`, or
2. The "I'm including the source code in my source code and hope that everything builds correctly" path: add foo.o to the things that `Biometry` needs, and add a recipe on how to build `foo.o` from `foo.c`, and add `foo.c` to your sources:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I../../include
CFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS = -L../../lib -L../../lib64
LIBS = -lbsapi

Biometry: main.c foo.o
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.c foo.o -o Biometry $(LIBS)

foo.o: foo.c
     $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) foo.c -o foo.o $(LIBS)
```

Comment: If this is [`tpl`](https://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/), then I'd recommend following the [installation guide](https://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/userguide.html#_build_and_install) for that.

Comment: It is.  I tried following the guide, by putting tpl.c and tpl.h into the same folder as my main program.  When I build, I get an error saying: undefined reference to (a function in tpl).

Comment: As said, you need to link against TPL code than, and add the `NOLIB` flag mentioned in the instructions. should work